# Python Linear Programming

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to solve the following equation:

`maximize x^{T}Ax`   where `x` is a `3 X 1` vector of the variables to be maximized and `A` is a `3 X 3` matrix of values.

So basically `x^{T} = [a,b,c]` which are the unknowns to be maximized and `A` could be something like

`A = [ [29, 29, 79],
      [28, 28, 48],
      [9, 40, 0 ]]`

Could someone show me how to represent this in the form of a maximization problem using PuLP or some other linear programming package in python?

Any help would be much appreciated. I am extremely new to this area and have not idea how to get started representing this formulation.

I have so far tried to use [CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/) to model this function.
I have the following code but am seeing an error:

```
    [1] A = np.array([[29,29,79],[28,28,48],[9,40,0]])
    [2] x=Variable(3)
    [3] objective=Minimize(x.T*A*x)
     Warning: Forming a nonconvex expression (affine)*(affine).
  warnings.warn("Forming a nonconvex expression (affine)*(affine).")
    [4] constraints=[0<=x,x<=1,sum_entries(x)==1] #what I'm trying to say is each entry of x should be between 0 and 1 and all entries should add up to 1.
    [5] prob = Problem(objective, constraints)
    [6] prob.solve()
    DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules.
```

Comment: Not all questions need code, but in this case it looks more like you just dumped the question and are hoping someone writes the solution for you. This isn't actually a programming question, it's a math question. You need to have a rudimentary understanding of Python before any answer here might help you.

Comment: Yes I have more than a rudimentary understanding of python. I'd just like someone to point me in the right direction as far as an example or some such thing is concerned as I completely lack any sort of understanding of the field of optimization or linear programming and the corresponding packages in python.

Comment: Sounds like you need a tutorial, because this is an XY problem. Your real question seems to be "How do I perform linear programming in Python" which appears Too Broad. A quick google search turned up [this tutorial about PuLP](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2012/11/solving-a-linear-programming-problem-with-python-pulp/) which might help you.

Comment: @AdamSmith I've seen that already. But they don't seem to be working with  quadratic terms in the objective which is what I have in my objective function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe PuLP supports quadratic programming (QP). Your model is quadratic and PuLP is only for linear programming models (LPs and MIPs). There are quite a few options to express QPs in Python. High performance commercial solvers often provide Python bindings, and otherwise you can look at for example [CVXOPT](http://cvxopt.org/). Notice that only convex QPs are "easy" to solve. If you have a non-convex QP things become much more difficult and you may need to look at a global solver (there not as many of those type of solvers). Non-convex QPs can be reformulated via the KKT conditions as a linear MIP model, although these models may not always perform very well.

Comment: thanks for the input. I'm currently using http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/  but I'm seeing an error when I try to put in the following objective function:  
 `A = np.array([[29,29,79],[28,28,48],[9,40,0]])
  objective=Minimize(x.T*A*x)
`
The error I'm seeing is `Forming a nonconvex expression (affine)*(affine).
  warnings.warn("Forming a nonconvex expression (affine)*(affine).")` . Any idea how I could fix that? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Cvxopt is for convex problems, and it seems you try to pass on a non-convex problem.

Comment: Hmm right but what I'm not understanding is, if the problem is inherently non-convex or if I can actually modify the representation of the objective function to make it convex? Meaning can I re-formulate the problem in some way to make it convex? @erwinkalvelagen

Comment: 1. Depends on the data in the Q matrix, 2. If you know how to that, there may be a Nobel prize waiting for you.

Comment: :) haha I see ok got it. What Q matrix are you referring to?

Comment: Everyone writes x'Qx. That is the usual notation. You probably should do some reading about this.